# Devise Timeout not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token, session-timeout

I can't get the timeoutable feature of devise to work. I have tried all the solutions I could find on googling around but still no luck. 
In DEVISE.RB I have

```
config.timeout_in = 5.seconds
```

In USER.RB I have

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable
```

And in ROUTES I have this

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations' }
```

The 5 seconds are just for testing...
If it may help, I am using Rails a backend for Ember...
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: After spending some time trying to understand how devise handles the log in I came to the conclusion that something must be wrong in the configuration...in particular I can't see anything related to log_out/session destroy and the like...
In my sessions controller I only have the create method, is this correct?